# Validation error "Entity: bad value for restricted picklist field: AccountCleanInfo" when I try to create custom field

Tags: custom-field, lookup, validation, account

When I try to create a custom field Territory (lookup on a custom object `Territory__c` that has name and lookup on parent `Territory__c`) for `Account` I see validation error:

> "There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the
>   affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was
>   "Entity: bad value for restricted picklist field: AccountCleanInfo"."

I'm not sure what exactly went wrong. Could you please help me to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That error is shown when you have a picklist with the checkbox checked for "Strictly enforce picklist values".

AccountCleanInfo is created and used Data.com Clean (via the SOAP API) to help identify where the data has been cleaned or not. My assumption is that there is a Trigger, Workflow Field Update, or some other piece of code that is trying to update `AccountCleanInfo` field on Account, but since it's not in the available picklist values it's throwing an error.

So my first recommendation is to see if there are any Workflows, Triggers, Process builder Processes that are updating that field.